# how to make a video play in reverse using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a requirement of playing a video in reverse mode. i.e. A video should play from end-of-file to the beginning-of-file on its loading, or may be with a button click.

I checked on with some documentation on phonegap site but got only info about media-play, pause, release and other related methods.

Can this actually be done with phonegap? Are there any plugins that can be integrated over?

Comment: dont know about phonegap,but in general i can give you an idea..A video is nothing but series of images changing @ very fast rate.Now if the images name are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and so on...you can traverse each image by appying a for loop(reverse)..make sure the images are light weight!!!

Comment: hmm.. the idea is exactly right.. but am unsure how I do it with jquery/javascript

Comment: ok ,should i give you a snippet about how to go about things,but it does not have anything to do with phonegap...it is just basic javascript??easy hai

Comment: that would be a great help @MESSIAH - it would definitely help me. I can then think of tweaking it with Phonegap

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder images where all your images are placed in ascending order.
Name them 1,2,3,4.jpg and so on.

[working sample!!!](http://mobile.i-xltech.com/jayesh/swim/)

Assuming that you have a `div` in your html which has a `image` who`s`id=relapce` and your images folder have around 75 images say,then try this--:

```
var counter = 0;
function play_reverse_forward() {   
    //////////////////////for forward///////////////////////////////////////////
    if (forward button is clicked!!!) {
        counter += 1;
        if (counter < 74) {
            document.getElementById('replace').src = "images/" + counter + ".jpg";
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////for reverse/////////////////////////////////////
    else if (if reverse button is clicked!!!) {
        counter -= 1;
        if (counter < 74) {
            document.getElementById('replace').src = "images/" + counter + ".jpg";
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that u need 24/25 images per second for a fluent transistion

Comment: this should logically work, Yes. I do not have a clue how to make my video into parts i.e. images :( @MESSIAH

Comment: U can use [ffmpeg](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) or any more user-friendly program :P

Comment: if you find the answer helpful,accept it as answer.Feel free to ask question if you have any?check the link that i updated!!!